# Storing uploaded images in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a web application with the [React + ASP.NET Core template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022). The application will have a form for uploading recipes, including an image. I am hosting the application as an Azure Web App (App Service).

My question is: What is the best practice when it comes to storing the uploaded images? The first thing that comes to mind, is [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/blobs), but I am unsure if this is actually the intended way? (I guess this is such a common feature, that there must be an intended way).

Bonus question: If it is actually Azure Blob Storage, is it just configured without any access restrictions, or should the files actually be protected and then delivered back via the API (which knows the credentials)?

Comment: how many images, how big and how do you want to access them?

Comment: @Ewan after upload, the recipes (and hence the images) should be publicly available. I haven't decided on a size limit yet, but I would imagine something like <3MB when uploaded and then scaled down to ~500kB after upload. In theory there is no limit on how many images could be uploaded, but it's one per recipe, so I'm guessing <1,000 for quite a while.

Comment: just put a blob column on your database table

Comment: @Ewan thanks. I actually thought this would be database abuse, but reading up on it, it’s seems like a very reasonable approach.

Comment: To summarize the existing comments and answers, using the database can be reasonable if you own the database server. In other words, if using it heavily doesn't add marginal cost. Otherwise, if the database is also a cloud service and metered by usage / workload, then use Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Regarding database check this out first https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751/13898633

Comment: If you want something you can use locally to emulate Azure Blob Storage be sure to check out Azurite. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio%2Cblob-storage

Answer (score 4):

Definitly recommend Azure Blob Storage. It is the intended way. It’s also VERY cheap.

Blobs in SQL have no advantage except a dependency less.

But now you lose a lot of other free stuff like caching, and a very easily scaleable solution. You can also easily view or delete your data because you are working with normal files.

With SQL you also are unnecesarry constantly moving data through your web app, both hitting your database and web app.

Usually your SQL is going to be your scale and cost problem, so I don’t recommend adding more stuff to that.

Comment: One thing SQL also provides, is an easy local version, for debugging. How do you handle that, when using Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen There's a file manager for blobstorage with allows you to check and open what you upload incredibly easily. Or you can just store a link in your database and open that with your browser

Comment: @inaba yea, I was just wondering if there was a solution where you didn't rely on an Azure resource for local debugging. But I may just be old fashioned :-)

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen why not though? Dunno what you mean by old fashioned. But it seems silly to want to store things on azure and not want to use their own tool to view them

Comment: @inaba it's not a huge issue. You do get an extra dependency for debug though. And - unless you make a separate storage for each developer - you suddenly share the storage. Ideally I would like to be completely free of anything in the cloud, while running local debug, But it's not that I refuse to do it no matter what :-)

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen Again this makes very little sense. You want azure but you also don't want it.. Being free of anything cloud when developing locally is easy though. You just make an interface for your uploader and implement it two times. One for your live with azure and another one for your debug with the file system

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen I get your point. I use a Azure storage test account, just a mess with all kind of stuff but it works pretty fine in practice for my projects.